# subsetting a list of html nodes

Tags: r, subset, rvest, accessor

I have a simplified example below.

```
library("rvest")
sample_html <- read_html('<span id="message"> text1 </span>
                <span id="message"> text2 <img src="https://url.com/emoji.svg" alt=":blue_heart:"> </span>')

messages <- html_elements(sample_html,"#message")
html_elements(messages,xpath = "//span[@id='message']//text() | //span[@id='message']//img")
```

When I the variable using `messages[2]`, it gives me "

```
{xml_nodeset (1)} [1] <span id="message"> text2 <img src="https://url.com/emoji.svg" alt=":blue_heart:"></span>
```

which makes sense. When I use `messages[[2]]` it returns "

```
{html_node}
<span id="message">
[1] <img src="https://url.com/emoji.svg" alt=":blue_heart:">
```

I looked up the difference between [] and [[]] but still can't figure out why the different results and where "text 2" is when calling `messages[[2]]`

Thank you very much!

****question update******
If I run the last line of code, regardless if I parse `messages`,
`messages[1]`

, or `messages[2]`, I get the same results of

> ```
> {xml_nodeset (3)}
> [1]  text1 
> [2]  text2 
> [3] <img src="https://url.com/emoji.svg" alt=":blue_heart:">
> ```

What I really want is to generate a list with the first item containing `text 1`, and the second item containing `text2` and `<img src="https://url.com/emoji.svg" alt=":blue_heart:">`

I tried to loop through each item in messages to parse `messages[i]`, that didn't help either.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In your example, `messages` is of class `xml_nodeset`:

```r
class(messages)
#> [1] "xml_nodeset"
```

This is "really" a `list` of individual html nodes, with a class attribute that allows it to have specific methods assigned, including the special print method shown when you type `messages` into the console that makes it look different to a "normal" R list.

You can see this if you `unclass` it, revealing a standard `list` of html nodes.

```r
unclass(messages)
#> [[1]]
#> {html_node}
#> <span id="message">
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> {html_node}
#> <span id="message">
#> [1] <img src="https://url.com/emoji.svg" alt=":blue_heart:">
```

As with other list-like objects in R, the `[` operator doesn't return the objects in the list, it returns a *subsetted* list. The object itself is obtained using the `[[` operator.

You can see this in the case of lists in the following example:

```r
mylist <- list("a", "b")

mylist[2]
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "b"

class(mylist[2])
#> [1] "list"

mylist[[2]]
#> [1] "b"

class(mylist[[2]])
#> [1] "character"
```

By analogy, with xml_nodeset objects, the `[` operator returns an xml_nodeset object. So `messages[2]` returns a length-1 xml_nodeset, not the actual `html_element` inside it. This subsetted nodeset retains all the characteristics of xml_nodesets.

To get the html node itself, we do `messages[[2]]`:

```r
messages[[2]]
#> {html_node}
#> <span id="message">
#> [1] <img src="https://url.com/emoji.svg" alt=":blue_heart:">
```

html_node objects are more complicated. They contain pointers to the original document. Although you can't see your text when it prints, it is still there:

```r
html_text(messages[[2]])
#> [1] " text2 "
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers! I have edited the original question with a follow-up, which is what triggered me to ask about this whole thing in the first place. If you could further shed light on that, that'd be great!